# Cauchy Hadamard formula and starting index of power series

Tags: analysis

The radius of convergence $r$ can be calculated for every power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ with $a_k\in \mathbb C$ and $z\in \mathbb C$ by using the Cauchy Hadamard formula:

$r = \limsup_{k\to\infty} |\frac{1}{a_k}|^{1/k}$ .

In every textbook I find the power series starting from $k=0$.

Can the Cauchy Hadamard formula also be used for a power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k$ directly (ie. without changing the index of the power series before calculating $r$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly. The two series converge for the same points $z$ and have the same radii of convergence. You can thing of the second as the first with $a_0=0$.

Comment: Ok that makes it clear. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. One term doesn't have any effect on convergence of a series.